# Database.com licenses in a Salesforce org

Tags: security, sharing, licenses, database.com

It seems it is possible add Database.com users into a 'normal' Salesforce.com org (i.e. a standard EE or UE org) to allow large numbers of users cheaper access to API and OAuth based authentication.

The documentation at http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_understanding_license_types.htm remarks "Access to data is determined by organization-wide sharing defaults."

So, my question is:

If the OWD is set to Private and a Database.com light user creates and manage their own records - can those records also be shared to internal Full License users for use in reporting, standard page layouts and Visualforce?

Comment: Confirmed by SF. You can add Database.com licenses to your organisation, however they do not add anything to your allowed limits (API and data storage).  Still waiting on the security answer tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed by SF.  You can add Database.com licenses to your organisation, however they do not add anything to your allowed limits (API and data storage).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use Database.com licenses against a Force.com org. I have asked this question of a couple of guys within Salesforce and have always been met with a no. It would be really interesting if you could as it would solve a few problems for me.

But currently I still think it is a no and the docs are slightly misleading.

Comment: I've seen a tweet from a Database.com product manager who said 'yes' and I've had a Salesforce Sales Engineer suggest it, I haven't managed to ask the follow up question which I pose above tho...

Comment: They announced at Dreamforce (can't remember which session) that Database.com licenses could now be mixed with Force.com ones.

Comment: Ah cool, that's where I missed it from. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am positive that this can be achieved .

We will have to create appropriate sharing rules .

Also if we want data access for Visualforce page if we write an extension class using "without sharing" keyword we will run in a system context mode and we can perform operation ignoring sharing permissions .

In short if OWD  Private sharing rules can be written both programatically and manually .